# Check if double is dividable without a remainder

Tags: c#, .net

I need to check if my double number is dividable by 0.05 without remainder. So i'm doing this:

```
if (!double.TryParse(ProductPriceTextBox.Text, out price) || !(0 < price) || !(price%0.05==0.0))
```

The problem is that my ProductPrice can consist out of 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 2 euros in coins.

So all the product prices must be: `price%0.05==0`, that is:

1 euro, 1.5 euro, 0.5 euro - pass
1.21 euro, 0.01 euro - fail.

But compiler prompts me on:

```
(price%0.05==0.0)
```

> Comparison of floating point numbers with equality operator. Possible loss of prescision

Can't figure out why it fails...

Of course I can do this:

```
int priceInCents= price*100;
(priceInCents%5==0)
```

But I think there is an other way.

Comment: Floating point values are inherently imprecise. You will get rounding errors. Please read *[What Every Computer Scientist
Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1011/FPComp/floatingmath.pdf)*

Comment: This kind of calculations (involving `==`) should not use double or float but decimal!! (Or possibly an epsilon condition)

Comment: so you say i should use cents to check this

Comment: sort of, yes. you need a datatype that is non-binary. decimal is for exact repesentation of decimal numbers.

Comment: The problem which the compiler is pointing out to you, is that when comparing two floating numbers that are close to each other or actually are equal, can give wrong results when comparing them using a PC. The reason behind this is, that the PC is not able to calculate something with a precision of 0.00001 or so, instead a number is represented in "steps", for example 1 step equals 0.25 (just an example). If you now have two numbers (1.1 and 1.15) and can not compare them correctly. I may be wrong but that is what my experience tells me

Comment: Oh, no don't multiply by 100, change the data type!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd better use the `decimal` data type, since that is more fitting for currencies. (`double` is a floating point data type, and that is no fun with currencies, since it isn't precise).

Try this:
    decimal price;

```
if ( !decimal.TryParse(ProductPriceTextBox.Text, out price)
     || !(0 < price)
     || !(price % 0.05M == 0)
   )
```

Comment: @Cheese: Check. `.05` is a float, you need `M` to let the compiler know it is a `decimal`, so `.05M` works.

Answer (score 1):

Whole numbers are so much easier to deal with .....

```
if ((!double.TryParse(ProductPriceTextBox.Text, out price)
  || (price * 20.0 != Math.Floor(price * 20.0)) )
  {   // failure
```

Answer (score -1):

Multiply your price with 100 and modulus by 5

```
!((price*100) % 5 == 0)
```

Comment: i sugessted this in my question, but i was thinking that maybe there is other solution

Comment: @TaW "... either". You are right. All calculations using `float` are unreliable.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read it to the end. You should use decimal instead:
decimal price = decimal.Parse(input);
!(price  % (decimal).05 == (decimal)0.0)